# htaccess command to prevent master site access via subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have hosting setup with a master domain (mapped to the web root) and then a number of addon domains (each with their own folder within the web root). At the moment you can visit www.masterdomain.com/addondomainsubdir and reach the same page as you would if you visited www.addondomain.com (which maps to /public_html/addondomainsubdir). I want to prevent this so if you visit www.masterdomain.com/addondomainsubdir then it will do a 301 redirect to www.addondomain.com. The new addondomain.com site is a single page site so it does not have to map any additional pages.

Adding rules to the htaccess file in the web root does notaffect anything as the subdir exists which is wierd as i thought the htaccess command should work even if there is a matching subdir (i've tried the following which works when there's no matching subdir):

```
RewriteRule ^addondomainsubdir?$ http://www.addondomain.com [NC,R=301,L]
```

Logically given it's reaching this directory I figure i need to add a command within the htaccess file in the addondomainsubdir directory however nothing appears to have any effect (i've got various other rules setup and they work fine).

I would be massively grateful if anyone explain the best way to rectify this?

Thanks so much for your help,

Dave

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but it has never been successfully answered. So for all of you finding this via search, this should do what the OP is asking.

Add this line to your `.htaccess` file:

```
redirect permanent /addondomainsubdir/ http://www.addondomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# for http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?masterdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ http://www.$1.com/ [R=301,L]

# for https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?masterdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ https://www.$1.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help but unfortunately this does not appear to have any effect at all and i'm really not sure why? :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a rule in your main .htaccess, I would make make a .htaccess for each add-on domain, putting each one in the respective subdirectory.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} masterdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^addondomainsubdir(.*)$ http://www.addondomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense however it does not seem to have any effect and I can't work out why, i have added your code to my existing code in the subdir htaccess file but www.masterdomain.com/addondomainsubdir does not redirect at all. If i visit it without the www then it gets redirected due to my redirection of non-canonical hostnames:
rewritecond %{http_host} !^(www\.([^.]+)\.com)?$
rewritecond %{http_host} ^(www\.)?([^.]+)\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ 
rewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.addondomain.com/$1 [L,R=301], but i cannot work out why your code isn't working? :(

Comment: You don't happen to have a RewriteBase in your .htaccess, do you?